# Can't Play Sounds on FoxDot

Tags: python, supercollider

I tried to evaluate FoxDot.start on SuperCollider but it shows SynthDef error:-

`**ERROR: SynthDef makeSound not found FAILURE IN SERVER /s_new SynthDef not found** etc.`

On FoxDot, it didn't say any error but produce no sound. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate these two lines:

```
Quarks.install("FoxDot")
FoxDot.start
```